# What is wrong with my intersection between two lists function

Tags: haskell

I want the intersection between two lists but it is only prints when they are at the same position.

```
inter [] _ = []
inter _ [] = []
inter (x:xs) (y:ys) = if (x == y) then x:inter xs ys else inter xs ys
```

Comment: `x` and `y` may not be equal, but that doesn't mean `x` isn't equal to something else in `ys`. Same goes for `y` vs `xs`.

Comment: How could I fix that?

Comment: You should give that question some thought.

Comment: inter (x:xs) (y:ys) = if (x == y) then x:inter xs ys else inter (x:xs) ys  Now its an empty list

Comment: Now you're ignoring the possibility that `y` could be somewhere else in the first argument. This isn't a problem where you can iterate over the two lists in parallel.

Comment: Can we assume both lists are sorted and have no repeating elements?

Comment: I think at this point it's more important for the OP to figure out how to write the naive O(n^2) version than to worry about how to optimize it for orderable values.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, your function iterates over both lists at the same time and appends elements to the result list, if the same element appears in both lists at the same location.

From what I've understood, what you really want to do is to add all elements from the first list that appear *anywhere* in the second list. So you may want to define (or use) another function that checks whether an element appears somewhere in a list, e.g. if you are having a list of `Int`s:

```
elem :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
```

or if you are already aware of what type classes are:

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

Using that function, you can process the first list element-wise and filter out all elements from that list that appear somewhere in the second list.

As you are obviously trying to learn Haskell, I do not want to spoil the experience for you and provide a more complete solution.